# Why doesn't a module initializer fire for an interface usage

Tags: c#, .net

## The code

So I have two assemblies

"AssemblyWithClassAndModuleInit" contains a class

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
}
```

"AssemblyWithInterfaceAndModuleInit" Contains an interface

```
public interface MyInterface
{
}
```

Both contain a module initializer

```
public static class ModuleInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ModuleInitializer", "true");
    }
}
```

Tests for "AssemblyWithClassAndModuleInit" (note `MyBaseClass` is used as the base for `ClassTests`)

```
[TestFixture]
public class ClassTests : MyBaseClass
{
    [Test]
    public void EnsureModuleInitIsCalled()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("true", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ModuleInitializer"));
    }
    [Test]
    public void EnsureAssemblyIsLoaded()
    {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        Assert.IsTrue(assemblies.Any(x => x.GetName().Name == "AssemblyWithClassAndModuleInit"));
    }
}
```

Tests for "AssemblyWithInterfaceAndModuleInit"  (note `MyInterface` is used as the interface for `InterfaceTests`)

```
[TestFixture]
public class InterfaceTests : MyInterface
{
    [Test]
    public void EnsureModuleInitIsCalled()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("true", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ModuleInitializer"));
    }
    [Test]
    public void EnsureAssemblyIsLoaded()
    {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        Assert.IsTrue(assemblies.Any(x => x.GetName().Name == "AssemblyWithInterfaceAndModuleInit"));
    }
}
```

The only test that fails is `InterfaceTests.EnsureModuleInitIsCalled`.

## The Question

So why is this? Shouldn't the fact that `InterfaceTests` implements `MyInterface` cause the module initializer to run?

## How am I injecting the Module Initializer

I am using IL weaving. Specifically https://github.com/Fody/ModuleInit

It detects this

```
public static class ModuleInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        //Init code
    }
}
```

And adds this

```
static <Module>()
{
    ModuleInitializer.Initialize();
}
```

## Updates

- As an aside if i add a field `Type interfaceType = typeof(MyInterface);` to `InterfaceTests` then all the tests pass.
- Coding was done against .net 4.5

## Full Source

Here is a repro with unit tests https://github.com/SimonCropp/Experiments/tree/master/ModuleInitRepro

Comment: Might be important to mention which CLR version you are using.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention Fody at all - presumably that's the magic which makes the module initializer class do anything? (Otherwise, it's not clear to me what *does* do that...)

Comment: This example is a bit confusing. Maybe it's better to do something like this:

var ifacetype = typeof(MyInterface);
Assert.AreEqual("true", etc);

This makes it more clear that you expect the module initializer to run when you first use a type of the module.

Comment: @JonSkeet yep it is Fody that is injecting the module init. I have update the question

Comment: @GeertvanHorrik interesting that if i add a field "Type interfaceType = typeof(MyInterface);" to InterfaceTests then all the tests pass

Comment: @leppie 4.5. updated question

Comment: C++/CLI uses a module initializer to initialize static C++ state.  I checked, just using typeof() on an exported interface type is enough to trigger it.  So it is not the CLR that's causing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obviously potentially relevant thing: your test class derives from your base class in the prod assembly. Therefore creating an instance of the test class requires calling the constructor in the base class (implicitly) which means the base class needs to be fully loaded and initialized, and therefore the assembly needs to be initialized.

Compare that with your interface version - the fact that you implement the prod-assembly interface in your test class is effectively irrelevant at execution time, as you're not doing anything which requires the interface.

I *suspect* that if you had:

```
public void Foo(MyInterface x)
{
}

[Test]
public void EnsureAssemblyIsLoaded()
{
    Foo(this);
    ... assertions ...
}
```

then that *may* initialize the assembly. If you had any methods declared in the interface, and you called one of those methods from `Foo`, then I'd definitely expect the assembly to be initialized.